# Sync two directories with NodeJS in both directions

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, filesystems

**I've tried everything, looked everywhere, even tried to code my own program. I am lost.**

The Idea: Two directories with the same set of files. Renaming a file in one renames it in the other. Editing a file in one edits it in the other. Same goes for deletion. And these changes should apply even if another program is autonomously making the changes.

And all of that, but also 2 ways. So making changes in Directory A makes the same changes to Directory B, but in addition, making changes to Directory B makes changes to Directory A.

The question is, can it be done?

```
/* Require Packages */
const $ = Object.assign.apply(0, ([
    'fs',
    'path',
    'readline'
]).map(a => ({ [a]: require(a) })));

/* Define Functions */
const _ = ({
    sls: {
        index: {},
        listen: function (a, b) {
            _.sls.index[a] = b;
        },
        trigger: function (a, b) {
            _.sls.index[a](b);
        }
    },
    inquire: function (a, b) {
        let x = $.readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });
        x.question(a, c => _.sls.trigger('question', c));
        _.sls.listen('question');
        return _.sls.listen('question', b);
    },
    walk: function (a) {
        return $.fs.statSync(a).isDirectory() ? $.fs.readdirSync(a).map(b => _.walk($.path.join(a, b))) : a;
    },
    regex: function (a, b) {
        return new RegExp(a.replace(/[-\/\\^$+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&').split('*').join(b));
    },
    match: function (a, b, c) {
        let x = $.path.parse(a), y = null, z = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < b.length; ++b) {
            y = $.path.parse(c + b[i].context).dir.split('/');
            for (let j = 0; j < x.dir.split('/').length; ++j) {
                if (_.regex(y[j], '.').test(x.dir.split('/')[j])) {
                    for (let k = 0; k < b[i].match.length; ++k) {
                        if (b.type == 'regex') {
                            z = new RegExp(b[i].match[k]).test(x.base);
                        } else {
                            z = _.regex(b[i].match[k], '.*').test(x.base);
                            if (b.type == 'exclude') z = !z;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return z;
    },
    watch: function (a, b) {
        for (let i of b) $.fs.watch($.path.format({
            dir: $.path.parse($.path.normalize(i) + $.path.normalize(a).split($.path.normalize(b[0])).join('')).dir,
            base: $.path.parse(a).base
        }), {}, function (a, b) {
            console.log(b);
        });
    }
});

/* Execute Script */
$.fs.readFile('sync.json', function (a, b) {
    if (a) {
        console.log('No configuration file was found. One is being generated now.');
        $.fs.writeFile('sync.json', JSON.stringify({
            targets: [
                'C:/sync-this-directory',
                'C:/and-this-one',
                'D:/and-this-one'
            ],
            patterns: [{
                type: 'include',
                context: '/include-matches-only-in-this-directory',
                match: ['*.*', 'by default all files are excluded']
            }, {
                type: 'exclude',
                context: '/exclude-matches-only-in-the-subdirectories-of-this-directory/*',
                match: ['*.exclude_this_extension', 'exclude_this_filename.*']
            }, {
                type: 'include',
                context: '/*',
                match: ['(a,b,c,d)', 'would match any file with a, b, c, and d in the name']
            }, {
                type: 'include',
                context: '/*',
                match: ['[1,2,3,4].*', 'would match any file with 1, 2, 3, or 4 in the name']
            }, {
                type: 'include',
                context: '/*',
                match: ['{1,b,3,d}.*', 'would match any file with ONLY 1, b, 3, or d in the name']
            }, {
                type: 'include',
                context: '/*',
                match: ['these-characters{([1,a],[2,b]),([3,c],[4,d])}', 'patterns are checked in entry order']
            }, {
                type: 'regex',
                context: '/*',
                match: ['these matches are regex-enabled', 'all matches will be included, not excluded']
            }]
        }));
    } else {
        _.inquire('Once you have ensured all configured target directories and their contents match, press enter.', function () {
            let x = null;
            try { x = JSON.parse(String(b).split('/').join('\/')); } catch (g) {
                console.log('Parsing Error: Your config is fucked. Fix it.');
                throw new Error();
            }
            console.log('Your files are now in sync. A change to one is a change to all.');
            let y = Object.assign.apply(0, _.walk(x.targets[0]).map(function (a) {
                return a.constructor.name == 'Array' ? a : [a];
            }));
            for (let i of y) if (_.match(i, x.patterns, x.targets[0])) _.watch(i, x.targets);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the program I wrote to try and solve it. The program also tries to allow for even more simultaneous synced directories and advanced conditional file inclusion. The part that copies the files back and forth is missing from here as I wrote it seperately.

Comment: How do you handle conflicts? If a given file is updated in one directory at the same time as it is deleted in the other?

Comment: I don't need this system to handle every possible contingency. I just need a basic system for 2-way sync so my developer can add plugins to my minecraft server. He is using my dropbox account as a way to access the plugins folder but the plugins folder in the dropbox folder must stay synced with the plugins folder in the server folder. Since he needs to modify it and you can't change the name of the dropbox folder, and because the plugins themselves generate configs, a 2-way system is required for complete functionality.